# curl_easy_perform() failed: failed FTP upload (the STOR command) error

Tags: c++, c, curl

I have been unsuccessful in uploading a file onto a FTP server with "curl_easy_perform() failed: failed FTP upload (the STOR command) " as an error.i googled a lot but can't find any solution or suggestion. here is my tiny code

```
#define LOCAL_FILE      "D:/er.txt"      
#define REMOTE_URL      "ftp://ftp.nso.edu/incoming/" 

using namespace std;


static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  curl_off_t nread;

  size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);
  return retcode;
}


int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;
  curl_off_t fsize;

  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;


  /* get the file size of the local file */ 
  if(stat(LOCAL_FILE, &file_info)) {
    printf("Couldnt open '%s': %s\n", LOCAL_FILE, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

  printf("Local file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);

  /* get a FILE * of the same file */ 
  hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {


    /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* specify target */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);

    /* pass in that last of FTP commands to run after the transfer */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

    /* now specify which file to upload */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    /* Set the size of the file to upload (optional).  If you give a *_LARGE
       option you MUST make sure that the type of the passed-in argument is a
       curl_off_t. If you use CURLOPT_INFILESIZE (without _LARGE) you must
       make sure that to pass in a type 'long' argument. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)fsize);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* clean up the FTP commands list */ 
    curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

  curl_global_cleanup();         




  // Wait for keystroke
   getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the actual URL you are using? It doesn't seem to be generally available (or it's down).

Comment: i had checked it out.. its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, char* allocatedMemoryForErrorBuffer);
```

The character pointer will have a bit more detail about the error that is occurring. Typically, this works for HTTP requests but my understanding is that it should work for FTP as well.

Comment: after doing that what you have suggested i am getting the following error at the line that you suggested  -  expected primary-expression before "char"

Comment: I think plaknas means `char *aBuffer = new char [1000];` and then pass `aBuffer` to setopt, not exactly as typed.

Comment: Yeah, allocate memory and then pass it to curl_easy_setopt. I think CURL takes care of the memory reallocation as needed, but since this is just for debugging, static allocation should be fine. Printing the buffer will tell you what is happening. My hunch is that there is something wrong at the server end..